# DataGridView ComboBox column won't set value

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a DataGridView that i load into it some results from an SQL ,
2 of the columns are DataGridView ComboBoxcolumns.

One column shows a year dropdown and ther other leave types.

The leave types one sets the value fine to the one fetched for the row, the year one though doesnt .

Here is my code

```
$years = [pscustomobject]@()
for ($i = 2010; $i -le ((get-date).Year + 5); $i++)
{
    $years += [pscustomobject]@{ Year = $i}
}
Write-Host $years.GetType()
Write-Host $years
Write-Host $querycombo.gettype()
Write-Host $querycombo
$ColumnComboboxYear                     = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
$ColumnComboboxYear.DataPropertyName    = 'Year'
$ColumnComboboxYear.Name                = 'Year'
$ColumnComboboxYear.HeaderText          = 'Year'
$ColumnComboboxYear.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = 'WhiteSmoke'
$ColumnComboboxYear.FlatStyle           = 'Popup'
$ColumnComboboxYear.Width               = 110
$DGVtimeAttendance.Columns.Insert(3, $ColumnComboboxYear)
$DGVtimeAttendance.Columns.RemoveAt(4)
$ColumnComboboxYear.Items.AddRange($years.year)

$ColumnCombobox                     = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
$ColumnCombobox.DataPropertyName    = 'Leave Type'
$ColumnCombobox.Name                = 'Leave Type'
$ColumnCombobox.HeaderText          = 'Leave Type'
$ColumnCombobox.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = 'WhiteSmoke'
$ColumnCombobox.FlatStyle           = 'Popup'
$ColumnCombobox.Width               = 110
$DGVtimeAttendance.Columns.Insert(4, $ColumnCombobox)
$DGVtimeAttendance.Columns.RemoveAt(5)
$ColumnCombobox.Items.AddRange($querycombo.types_ofleaves)
#object that is the row that i am testing
@{id=3; Employee=Philippos Ioannou; Date=01/20/2022 08:00:00 - 01/25/2022 13:00:00; Year=2022; Leave Type=Annual Leave; Comments=12312312}
System.Object[]
@{ Year = 2010 } @{ Year = 2011 } @{ Year = 2012 } @{ Year = 2013 } @{ Year = 2014 } @{ Year = 2015 } @{ Year = 2016 } @{ Year = 2017 } @{ Year = 2018 } @{ Year = 2019 } @{ Year = 2020 } @{ Year = 2021 } @{ Year = 2022 } @{ Year = 2023 } @{ Year = 2024 } @{ Year = 2025 } @{ Year = 2026 } @{ Year = 2027 }
System.Object[]
@{ types_ofleaves = Annual Leave } @{ types_ofleaves = Sick Leave } @{ types_ofleaves = Maternity Leave } @{ types_ofleaves = Army Leave } @{ types_ofleaves = Paternity Leave } @{ types_ofleaves = Study Leave } @{ types_ofleaves = Unpaid Leave } @{ types_ofleaves = Sympathy Leave }
```

At the end of the code i show the objects that are loaded into the ComboBoxes.

Also both fields in the db are declared as varchar

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it.

The object in years was an integer while the other one was a string. I converted it to a string and it worked fine:

```
$years += [pscustomobject]@{ Year = $i.tostring()}
```